# How to install old SDK platform

Tags: android

I want to test against Android 1.3 platform instead of latest 2.2.

Here is how my Android SDK and AVD Manager look likes.
[image]

However, I was expecting (screen from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#components), so that I can select old platform.
[image]

Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run Help > Check for Updates first, to update your Eclipse plug-in, then you can access the repository. Why would you want to test against 1.3? If anything is still on that old a version of Android (was there even a 1.3? It's not listed [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)), it's an insignificant portion of the market. The earliest you should even worry about is 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Also - on the bottom of the first screen between "Delete Add-on Site..." and "Refresh" uncheck the "Display updates only" check box.