# Facing problem with android SDK while installing

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

Before I got some problem while importing the project into the editor. So, I thought that was the problem of the sdk and tried to reinstall that and took one of the other SDK from my friend and I have done all the things for the installation and at the end it has recommended me to restart the eclipse then after restarted the IDE it is showing some error

[image: like this]

Then I went to SDK manager and tried to install some tools which it has downloaded from the net by itself but the problem is not solved. Can any one help me in this case?

Comment: goto `Windows` >> `preferance` >> click `Android` >> at right side what is `sdk Location` ?

Comment: it is some thing like this i think the path of the sdk  D:\mindtech\android-sdk_r04-windows\android-sdk-windows. Tell me do i need to change any thing in this? Thanks for the response

Comment: now tell me , at bottom there are avd list are show?

Comment: I think no. But which bottom you want me to see. And then i think this conversation will end because there are no many comments are allowed here with my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

looks like somebody else already had the same problem: [Huh? "SDK Platform Tools component is missing!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527414/huh-sdk-platform-tools-component-is-missing)

```
Open Eclipse. Then:
  Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager
   > Available Packages: 
     > Android Repository:
       + Android SDK Tools, revision 8
       + Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 1

[Install Selected]
```

Comment: yes, i have done that before it self.Eclipse itself recommended me for doing that because of error which i have. But i did not clear the error