# Android SDK Manager could not find packages

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I'm trying to install platform-tools and other support packages to develop Android application using with Eclipse.

But I got this scene at Android SDK Manager.
I can't see any "not installed" package like platform-tools , API , etc..

Any idea?
Thanks.

[image: androidsdkmanagerscene]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527414/huh-sdk-platform-tools-component-is-missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that tools->settings->force https... is checked, check android sdk tools, then the install button  will be enabled, now install 1 package (restart sdk manager)and after that other sdks will appear. (dont forget to close eclipse, and disable your antivirus while doing that) . this worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Run SDK Manager as an Administrator.

How:

- Right Click on SDK Manager
- select run as an Administrator

Answer (score 2):

- open sdk manager -> click tools -> options -> clear cache ->close
- click packages -> reload

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when my computer is connected to the Internet through the company proxy server. The only solution I found is to connect computer directly to the Internet, without proxy.