# Android - SDK platform-tools is missing?

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to make my SD card the default for downloading apps, and I'm using this [guide](http://addictiveblogs.com/how-to-move-all-android-apps-to-sd-card-without-rooting-device/)

I've downloaded only the SDK Tools, as written there. The problem is that I don't have the platform tools package, which is required for it.  I've done it already but it's another computer so that's why I didn't have the program.

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527414/sdk-platform-tools-component-is-missing) page and wrote this command:

```
android.bat update sdk --no-ui
```

It says it failed to fetch the URLS and then says there's nothing to update. What should I do?

**Note:** I downloaded it to `/:D`, could it cause the problem? I didn't have much space on `C`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think calling update I enough, you need to install the platform tools explicitly. Please see how to use the non-UI SDK manager here: [Updating SDK from command line](http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line)

Comment: nevermind, it was only a problem with the https, thanks!!