# Delphi 10.1 Berlin and Android SDK tools - zipalign and adb not found

Tags: android, delphi, adb, android-sdk-tools, delphi-10.1-berlin

[image]

Did anyone resolve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SDK Platform Tools component is missing!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527414/sdk-platform-tools-component-is-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Google recently changed the package and location of zipalign in SDK Rev. 23 and the IDE is no longer able to find the file.

1. Run the SDK Manager and upgrade the Android SDK Tools to version
   23.0.2 and Android SDK Platform-tools to version 20.
2. Once the above items are installed a new item will appear in the list: 
   Android SDK Build-tools version 20.  Select and install this
   package, it is the new package location for zipalign.
3. Update the
   IDE to point to the new location for zipalign.  Off of the main menu
   in the IDE select Tools | Options | Environment Options | SDK
   Manager.  Update the ZipAlign location to point to the new
   Build-Tools 20 directory.  By default in RAD Studio XE6 this will be
   C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\zipalign.exe.
   It will be in a similar location for Appmethod.

Answer (score 1):

`adb` is a part of the optional `platform-tools` package which if needed should be installed separately from the `SDK Manager`.

`aapt` and `zipalign` come with the `build-tools` package. Unlike `platform-tools` (every version of which gets installed into the same folder) each version of `build-tools` installs into its own subfolder - so you may want to make sure that your Delphi config points to the desired (and installed) version.